# Who made a pilgrimage to Jerusalem on the three Regalim?

Tags: history, travel, chagim-holidays, yerushalayim-jerusalem

When the Temple stood in Jerusalem, and "all of Israel" were required to make a pilgrimage on the three *regalim*, who actually make the pilgrimage? I suppose a single city could not house *all* the Jews.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See the Mishna in Chagigah (Perek 1 - Chapter 1) :

> פרק א - משנה א הַכֹּל חַיָּבִין בָּרְאִיָּה, חוּץ מֵחֵרֵשׁ, שׁוֹטֶה
>   וְקָטָן, וְטֻמְטוּם, וְאַנְדְּרוֹגִינוֹס, וְנָשִׁים, וַעֲבָדִים
>   שֶׁאֵינָם מְשֻׁחְרָרִים, הַחִגֵּר, וְהַסּוּמָא, וְהַחוֹלֶה,
>   וְהַזָּקֵן, וּמִי שֶׁאֵינוֹ יָכוֹל לַעֲלוֹת בְּרַגְלָיו. אֵיזֶהוּ
>   קָטָן, כֹּל שֶׁאֵינוֹ יָכוֹל לִרְכּוֹב עַל כְּתֵפָיו שֶׁל אָבִיו
>   וְלַעֲלוֹת מִירוּשָׁלַיִם לְהַר הַבַּיִת, דִּבְרֵי בֵית שַׁמַּאי.
>   וּבֵית הִלֵּל אוֹמְרִים, כֹּל שֶׁאֵינוֹ יָכוֹל לֶאֱחֹז בְּיָדוֹ שֶׁל
>   אָבִיו וְלַעֲלוֹת מִירוּשָׁלַיִם לְהַר הַבַּיִת, שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר (שמות כג)
>   שָׁלֹשׁ רְגָלִים

All are obligated in seeing [the Temple Mount], except for a deaf mute, an incompetent, or a minor; an intersexual, an androgyne; women, unfreed slaves; a lame person, a blind person, or a sick person; or an old person who cannot stand upon his feet. Who is a minor? Anyone who cannot ride on his father's shoulders and go up from Jerusalem to the Temple Mount, according to the House of Shammai; The House of Hillel say: Anyone who cannot hold his father's hand and go up from Jerusalem to the Temple Mount, for it says, "Three regalim" [legs] (Exodus 23:14)

In regards to the city of Jerusalem being able to house, see the Mishna in Pirkei Avos (5 - 5) which says that a miracle occurred in Jerusalem so that during the Regalim, Jerusalem was able to sustain the large number of people staying for the Chag:

> עֲשָׂרָה נִסִּים נַעֲשׂוּ לַאֲבוֹתֵינוּ בְּבֵית הַמִּקְדָּשׁ {טו}. לֹא
>   הִפִּילָה אִשָּׁה מֵרֵיחַ בְּשַׂר הַקֹּדֶשׁ {טז}, וְלֹא הִסְרִיחַ
>   בְּשַׂר הַקֹּדֶשׁ {יז} מֵעוֹלָם, וְלֹא נִרְאָה זְבוּב בְּבֵית
>   הַמִּטְבָּחַיִם {יח}, וְלֹא אֵרַע קֶרִי לְכֹהֵן גָּדוֹל בְּיוֹם
>   הַכִּפּוּרִים {יט}, וְלֹא כִבּוּ גְשָׁמִים אֵשׁ שֶׁל עֲצֵי
>   הַמַּעֲרָכָה, וְלֹא נָצְחָה הָרוּחַ אֶת עַמּוּד הֶעָשָׁן {כ}, וְלֹא
>   נִמְצָא פְסוּל בָּעֹמֶר וּבִשְׁתֵּי הַלֶּחֶם וּבְלֶחֶם הַפָּנִים,
>   עוֹמְדִים צְפוּפִים וּמִשְׁתַּחֲוִים רְוָחִים, וְלֹא הִזִּיק {כא}
>   נָחָשׁ וְעַקְרָב בִּירוּשָׁלַיִם מֵעוֹלָם, **וְלֹא אָמַר אָדָם
>   לַחֲבֵרוֹ צַר לִי הַמָּקוֹם שֶׁאָלִין בִּירוּשָׁלַיִם**

Ten miracles were performed for our forefathers in the Temple: (1) No woman had a miscarriage from the smell of the sanctified meat. (2) The sanctified meat never became rancid. (3) A fly was never seen in the slaughterhouse. (4) The High Priest never experienced a seminal emission on Yom Kippur [Day of Atonement]. (5) Rain never extinguished the fire of the arranged wood. (6) Wind never won out over the pillar of smoke. (7) The Omer [barley offering], the Two Loaves, and the Showbread were never found to be invalid. (8) People standing were crowded, but bowing had space. (9) Never did a snake nor scorpion ever cause harm in Jerusalem. **(10) A person never said to his fellow, 'It is too crowded for me to sleep overnight in Jerusalem.**

Comment: See also Tosafos on *P'sachim* ([3b](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=4&daf=3b&format=text), s.v. מאליה), who indicates that someone who doesn't own land in Israel is not obligated to travel to make a pilgrimage for the *shalosh r'galim* (though there are various subtle differences in how to understand that Tosafos; see [*Chevel Nachalato* 8:11](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%97%D7%91%D7%9C_%D7%A0%D7%97%D7%9C%D7%AA%D7%95_%D7%97_%D7%99%D7%90)).

Comment: Didn't someone besides the listed exempt classes have to stay elsewhere to defend the countryside from the Assyrians or whoever?  I'm not sure if there was a standing army during the First Temple, but the same question could apply under the Hasmoneans.

Comment: @Mike Refer to Shemot 34:24 "No man will covet your land". Da'at Zekenim coomentary says that other nations that used to control the land will recognize that because Israel is doing mitzvot, G-d protects them and the land, and they don't even have a desire to conquer it. Thus, there is no need fo an army to protect the land.

Answer (score 4):

Pirkei Avot 5:5:

עֲשָׂרָה נִסִּים נַעֲשׂו לַאֲבוֹתֵינוּ בְּבֵית הַמִּקְדָּשׁ... וְלֹא אָמַר אָדָם לַחֲבֵרוֹ צַר לִי הַמָּקוֹם שֶׁאָלִין בִּירוּשָׁלַיִם:

Ten miracles were performed for our forefathers in the Temple: (10) A person never said to his fellow, 'It is too crowded for me to sleep overnight in Jerusalem.'

Thus, there was room to house **all** the Jews, theoretically.